# MongoDB try to access from one table to another table

Tags: mongodb

I am getting the DocumentID from Table1.
so I want to look into each table1 entries and go to the table2 and get the corresponding values.

```
$cursor = $table1->find();
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
    $ID1=  $obj['DocumentID'];

    $criteria = array('DocumentID'=>$ID1);      
    $fields = array('DocumentID', 'DocumentDetails');

        $cursor1 = $Documentid2details->find($criteria, $fields);
    echo $cursor1->count() . ' document(s) found. <br/>'; 

    foreach ($cursor1 as $obj1) {

        echo 'the feed details are  ' . $obj1['DocumentIDDetails'] . '<br/>';
        echo '<br/>';
    }
```

===

I have one table in which I have DocumentID and DocumentDetails.
another table with DocumentID and name.

I want to get the DocumentID from one table and keep that in the other table to get the document details.
I am having issue with the getting value from other table.
can you please let me know what I am missing

Comment: -1 since it should be well known (meanwhile) that you can not perform JOIN-ish queries across multiple collections in one query. That's why is it a NO-SQL database.

Comment: not convinced with -1. I am not doing in one query please check and coorrect me if Ia m wroong

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get data from 2 collections using 1 query with MongoDB. The premise is to denormalize, and if you cannot, perform the 2nd query and aggregate (join) the results in your programming layer.

Comment: can you please explain me with an example/url

Comment: Denormalize as in make your schema so that the details are a part of the main document. `{"name":"Somedoc","type":"document","details":[{"part":1,"quantity":2},{"part":2,"quantity":3}]}`

Answer (score 0):

Options:

- denormalize
- multiple queries
- using embedded documents

Comment: can you please provide me an example or reference